# How many possibilities are there to assign 4 people a number from 1 to 6 where exactly two have the same number?

Tags: combinatorics

Problem: Suppose there are four people A,B,C,D and each of them will be assigned a number from 1 to 6.
How many possibilities are there if exactly two of them will be assigned the same number and the other two will be assigned different numbers (which are different from each other)?

I have thought of 2 solutions with different outcomes and I don't see why they are logically different:

First of all we can think of this situation as how many tuples ($x_1$,$x_2$,$x_3$,$x_4$) are there where $x_1$ represents the number from 1 to 6 of A, $x_2$ of B etc.

Solution 1: First guarantee that three of the four tuple entries are different:
For $x_1$ we have 6 possibilities, for $x_2$ there are 5 possibilities and for $x_3$ there are 4 possibilities. For $x_4$ to be the only number which is repeated we have to choose $x_4$ to be either $x_1,x_2$ or $x_3$ so we have 3 possibilities. So in total there are $6*5*4*3=360$ possibilities.

Solution 2: Because two tuple entries have to be the same there are $\binom{4}2=6$ ways we can arrange them in the tuple, e.g (x,$x_2,x,x_4$)...
Now there are 6 possibilities for x, 5 possibilities for $x_2$ and 4 possibilities for $x_4$.
So in total $6*6*5*4=720$ possibilities.

After coding I know that 720 is right but I don't see the logical error I must have made in solution 1.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

In Solution 1, you forced person D to be one of the people with a shared number, so $360$ is "number of cases where D has a shared number."

You can multiply by $4$ to count the other cases where a given person X has a shared number. But then you need to divide by $2$ due to counting each case twice (e.g., $(1, 3, 1, 4)$ is counted in the "cases where A has a shared number" and "cases where C has a shared number").

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adjusting as you proceed by division /multiplication, it can be viewed as

- select the two who will share and allot one of the rooms, thus $_4C_2\times 6=36$
- place the remaining two in $_5P_2 =5\times4 =20$ ways

Thus ans $=36\times20 =720$